# Does the series converge $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Does the series converge?
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2n}}}$$

I tried to solve it with alternating series test and got $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=1\neq0\implies\text{??Divergence?? or how to prove that}$

Idea: To show that the limit of $(-1)^n$ doesnt exist, thus the series is divergent. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, this series is not convergent because sequence $$ \frac{(-1)^n}{\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}}$$ is not convergent. For a series $\sum_n {a_n}$ to be convergent, it is necessary (but not yet sufficient) that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: and because this limit doesn't tend to zero it is sufficient to say that the series diverges?

Comment: @BiliDebili the vanishing condition states that if a series is summable then $lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =0$. Since the series in question doesn't (the consequent, the latter condition) then by modus tollens the series is not summable.

Comment: This sequence doesn't have a limit, in particular it doesn't tend to zero, which is sufficient to tell that the series does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

Series diverges, as general member doesn't tends to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the behavior of $\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}$ for many $n$'s. Then evaluate the partial sums as $n$ increases.

It's a bit of a trick question.